# Unable to open a file in C

Tags: c, windows, file, fopen

I can't open a file in C, even though the file exists and isn't used by any application. Can someone tell me what is causing this problem?

```
int main()
{
    FILE* oud;
    unsigned size;
    unsigned* bytes;
    char path[] = "C:\\Users\\Ruben\\Documents\\test.txt";
    errno_t error;

    if ((error  = fopen_s(&oud, path, "rb" )) == NULL)
    {
        perror(NULL);
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(oud);
    getchar();
    return 0;
    }
}
```

The output is: "No error".

Comment: I don't know what the error could be, but the reason why you don't get a useful error message is likely because you call `perror(NULL);` instead of checking the error code returned by fopen_s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`fopen_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9(v=vs.80).aspx) returns `0` on success, not `NULL` on failure:

> Zero if successful; an error code on failure. See _doserrno, errno, _sys_errlist, and _sys_nerr for more information on these, and other, error codes.

The `NULL` macro is `#define`d to `0` (probably) which means if the file is opened the `if()` in the posted code is:

```
if (0 == 0)
```

which is obviously true. Change to:

```
if ((error = fopen_s(&oud, path, "rb" )) != 0)
```